# Not recognizing Date Type in Java MySQL DB Call

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following calls in one of my classes

```
@Override
public Integer save(NewsItem item){
    ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        String query = "INSERT INTO newsItem (type,title,content,link,layout,imageUri,timestamp)" +
                       "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1,item.getType());
        ps.setString(2,item.getTitle());
        ps.setString(3,item.getContent());
        ps.setString(4,item.getLink());
        ps.setInt(5,item.getLayout());
        ps.setString(6,item.getImageUri());
        ps.setDate(7,item.getTimestamp());

        return ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionUtility utility = new ConnectionUtility();
        utility.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

The **NewsItem** POJO has the following properties

```
    private Integer id;
    private Integer type;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String link;
    private Integer layout;
    private String imageUri;
    private Date timestamp;
```

Everything works and has been tested except for the **timestamp** call which is

```
ps.setDate(7,item.getTimeStamp())
```

I am able to set the **Date** on the **NewsItem** object by calling

```
item.setTimestamp(new Date());
```

but I get the error from my IDE (Eclipse) that tells me the following message

**The method setDate(int,Date) in the type NewsItemDAO is not applicable for the arguments
 setDate(int,Date)**

This has been a plague for me throughout the life of this application I have been working on because I have had to result to storing the timestamps as string for the time being.

If the column in my MySQL database is of type **DATETIME** is there a different way I should be saving that timestamp? Or is there something wrong with the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) expects [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), not [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

```
ps.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(item.getTimestamp().getTime()));
```

But the `java.sql.Date` contains only the date part of datetime, not the time part. You'd like to use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead.

```
ps.setTimestamp(7, new Timestamp(item.getTimestamp().getTime()));
```

Comment: Does this method work well with MySQL and can I still use java.sql.Timestamp the way Java.util.Date is used? Should the MySQL datatype for this be TIMESTAMP or DATETIME?

Comment: You should not use `java.sql.Timestamp` in your model object (POJO as you call it). Use it only during persisting in DB. On retrieving you can just upcast `ResultSet#getTimestamp()` to `java.util.Date`. As to the types, you can use both. The difference is only that `TIMESTAMP` is implicitly converted to UTC timezone and thus more recommended to avoid timezone headaches and unportability.

Comment: excellent! I made the changes. Everything looks great as long as I can go back and forth with the Date type on my POJO and the value when I pull it out of the Database.

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports - My guess is that you are using `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

If possible, it's a good idea to use `java.sql.Timestamp` which extends `java.util.Date` to avoid this confusion and enhance the readability of your code.

Comment: The problem is in this particular case not in the imports. The `Timestamp` recommendation is however seconded, but not only due to readability.